# NG Include Ionic Issues with phone

Tags: ionic-framework

I created an android build to test out on my phone.  I'm using ng-include to embed an html file.  It works using developer tools in Chrome, but not my phone and can't figure out why.

```
<div ng-include="'../templates/discover.html'"></div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

mm its a bad idea to use an absolute path, where is your templates folder?
you can use ng-include="'views/templates/sarasa.html'"